# Use SQLiteNetextensions with Xamarin for Android-App

Tags: android, xamarin, sqlite-net-extensions

I've read some threads about SQLite for Xamarin but I'm still not able to set up *SQLiteNetExtensions* in a proper way. I'm currently developing an android app with Target Framework Android 7.1(API Level 25 - Nougat).

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

1. I installed nuget packages:

   `Install-Package SQLiteNetExtensions -Version 2.0.0-alpha2 -Pre`

   `Install-Package SQLite.Net-PCL -Version 3.1.1`

   According to: https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions
2. Then I set up my code.

   ```
   using SQLite.Net.Attributes;
   using SQLiteNetExtensions.Attributes;
   using System;

   namespace AppName.Resources.Model
   {
     public class Entry
     {
       [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
       public int Id { get; set; }
       [ForeignKey(typeof(Stock))]
       public int StockId { get; set; }
       public DateTime Date { get; set; }
       public double Amount { get; set; }
     }
   }
   ```

   ```
   using SQLite.Net.Attributes;
   using SQLiteNetExtensions.Attributes;
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;

   namespace AppName.Resources.Model
   {
     public class Stock
     {
       [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }
       [OneToMany(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.All)]
       public List<Entry> Entrys { get; set; }
     }
   }
   ```

   ```
   using Android.Util;
   using AppName.Resources.Model;
   using SQLite.Net;
   using SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinAndroid;
   using SQLiteNetExtensions.Extensions;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.IO;

   namespace AppName.Resources.DataHelper
   {
     public class DataBase
     {
       string folder = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
       public bool CreateDataBase()
       {
         try
         {
           using (var stocksDBConnection = new SQLiteConnection(new SQLitePlatformAndroid(), Path.Combine(folder, "Stock.db")))
           {
             stocksDBConnection.CreateTable<Entry>();
             stocksDBConnection.CreateTable<Stock>();    
             return true;
           }
         }
         catch (SQLiteException ex)
         {
           Log.Info("SQLiteEx", ex.Message);
           return false;
         }
       }

       public bool InsertIntoTableStock(object stock)
       {
         try
         {
           using (var stocksDBConnection = new SQLiteConnection(new SQLitePlatformAndroid(), Path.Combine(folder, "Stock.db")))
           {
             stocksDBConnection.InsertWithChildren(stock);
             return true;
           }
         }
         catch (SQLiteException ex)
         {
           Log.Info("SQLiteEx", ex.Message);
           return false;
         }
       }
       ...
   ```
3. These References were added by nuget:

   > SQLite-net
   >
   > SQLite.Net
   >
   > SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinAndroid
   >
   > SQLiteNetExtensions
   >
   > SQLitePCLRaw.Batteries_green
   >
   > SQLitePCLRaw.Core
   >
   > SQLitePCLRaw.lib.e_sqlite3
   >
   > SQLitePCLRaw.provider.e_sqlite3
4. Occuring error:

   > 'SQLiteConnection' does not contain a definition for 'InsertWithChildren' and the best extension method overload 'WriteOperations.InsertWithChildren(SQLiteConnection, object, bool)' requires a receiver of type 'SQLiteConnection'
   >
   > 'SQLiteConnection' does not contain a definition for 'GetAllWithChildren' and the best extension method overload 'ReadOperations.GetAllWithChildren(SQLiteConnection, Expression>, bool)' requires a receiver of type 'SQLiteConnection'

Well that's how far I get. Anybody out there who knows what to do? Maybe remove conflicting references?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found out that:

```
Install-Package SQLiteNetExtensions -Version 2.0.0-alpha2 -Pre
```

depends on

```
Install-Package sqlite-net-pcl
```

instead of

```
Install-Package SQLite.Net-PCL -Version 3.1.1
```

But after removing all references, cleaning the solution and reinstalling the **two needed packages** there is no `SQLite.net` available anymore.
When trying to use `SQLite` instead:

> 'SQLiteConnection' does not contain a definition for 'InsertWithChildren' and the best extension method overload 'WriteOperations.InsertWithChildren(SQLiteConnection, object, bool)' requires a receiver of type 'SQLiteConnection'

I'm curious if it's even possible to develop Android-Apps with VS seamlessly. Since everything takes years to set up.

---

***EDIT:***

Well, after some days of pain in the a** the solution was to use the even newer pre release (alpha**3**) which wasn't even referenced to on the official pages. Currently I'm satisfied. :)

```
Install-Package SQLiteNetExtensions-netstandard -Version 2.0.0-alpha3 -Pre
```

Hope anybody may need this.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I'm sure that its just a version problem because I just tried your code and it works fine for me. Try installing `SQliteNetExtensions v 1.3.0` package from the NuGet package manager window in Visual Studio and nothing else. It will install all its dependencies.

Here is what I did - Try to do the same and see if this helps :

1. I Created a new Android Single View App Project in Visual Studio 
   (I'm using community 2017 - but it should not matter ) and created
   the `Stock` , `Entry` and `Database` Classes and pasted your given
   code respectively.
2. I installed only the `SQliteNetExtensions v 1.3.0` package from the NuGet Package Manager [image]
   It installed the following dependencies along with it, I didn't installed these myself.
   `SQLite.Net-PCL v3.0.5`
   `NewtonSoft.Json v6.0.8`

Here is what I got after installing just `SQliteNetExtensions v 1.3.0` package.

[image]

As you can see its showing an update for `SQLite.Net-PCL v3.0.5` to `v3.1.1` I tired also with the updated one and it still works fine , so its up to you to update or not.

Here a bit proof that its working fine. I also compiled and run the app on emulator and it works all fine.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The solution was to use: SQLiteNetExtensions-netstandard -Version 2.0.0-alpha3. Probably the solution mentioned here: https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions/issues/117/support-netstandard also works.

Answer (score 0):

Ok after a bit of searching , I came to know that the creator of this extension used a pattern called MvvmCross while developing it. So unless you are using that pattern model you will get this error.

For non-MvvmCross users they have to rebuild the source files and reference it in their project and not use the pre-compiled one, the one you are using.

Go to the fourth post on the following link
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/20117/sqlite-net-extensions-and-sqliteconnection here he tells how to rebuild from source in his post in a very brief manner.

Hope you will understand it but if not wait till I install Visual Studio and Xamarin and try it out myself so I can give you accurate steps.
It will take a while so till then , Kudos!

Here is the link to source files https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions/downloads/ 
Click on download repository

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But currently I'm not sure wether you're on the right track, since you are reffering to some quite old stuff, where they are still using the SQLite.Net-PCL nuget package. Maybe I'm wrong...

Comment: @Muffex See my new answer and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this after doing a whole load of updates. Hit the same issues.

- Uninstall ALL SQLite plugins. See attached pic/link below.
- Reinstall SQLiteNetExtensions and this installs all dependencies too, actually all files in that list except SQLite.Net-PCL.
- SQLiteNetExtensions installs SQLite-net-pcl but you need the other one too so, install SQLite.Net-PCL as well.
- Restart Visual Studio as it doesn't always pickup all newly installed packages, the reopen your solution.

That worked for me so hopefully it'll help someone else here too.

[image: SQLite plugin list]