# How to get Sqlite.net extensions working?

Tags: android, xamarin, sqlite-net, sqlite-net-extensions

I'm struggling to use Sqlite.net Extensions in my Xamarin Android app.

I get the exeption:

Don't know about System.Collections.Generic.List`1 [app_name.Model.modelName]

The problem is similar to:

[Sqlite extension is not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23463849/sqlite-extension-is-not-working-as-expected#)

and

[Use SQLiteNetextensions with Xamarin for Android-App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44617321/use-sqlitenetextensions-with-xamarin-for-android-app#)

but the answers from there are not working for me and I can't add comments, so I have to start a new question.

I was trying to install different sqlite.net extensions packages and got no result.

Using SQLite.Net Extensions-PCL 2.0.0-alpha2 gives me such exeption:

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'SQLite.Net, Version=3.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?

I'm using Sql-net library:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl/

Does anyone has a final solution to this problem, please?

**Edit:**

I had to create a new project and paste everything in from the old one.

I don't think that answers the issue, but it's enough for me...

Answer (score 0):

> I'm using Sql-net library:
>
> https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl/

The link here you give is the right lib, but you really installing this package? Cause you also said that you're installing `SQLite.Net Extensions-PCL 2.0.0-alpha2`.

Please try to install the package in the following screenshot, the latest stable version is 1.3.3:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I am installing the package from the screenshot. I've created a new project today, installed SQLite.Net Extensions-PCL 2.0.0-alpha2 and it seems to be working, so there must be something messed up in my original project. I don't know how to trace what's wrong, so probably I'll just have to copy-paste everything and see if it works in the new project... Or is there a way to reinstall all references in the old project?